# passing array of struct as a function argument (web3.py)

Tags: contract-development, transactions, web3.py

I want to call this method updateRewardsPercentageByTokens() , with web3.py but I fail .
please can you help me find a solution

updateRewardsPercentageByTokens code :

```
   function updateRewardsPercentageByTokens(EchelonReward[] memory newEchlonArray) public onlyOwner {
        if (0 != newEchlonArray.length) {
            delete rewardsPercentageByTokens;
            for (uint index = 0; index < newEchlonArray.length; index++) {
                EchelonReward memory echelon;
                echelon.echelonMaxValue = newEchlonArray[index].echelonMaxValue * 10 ** uint256(decimals());
                echelon.percentage = newEchlonArray[index].percentage;
                rewardsPercentageByTokens[index] = echelon;
            }
        }
    }
```

struct code :

```
  struct EchelonReward {
        uint256 echelonMaxValue;
        uint256 percentage;
    }
```

my code to call the function

```
from flask_restful import Resource,reqparse
from data import * 
import argparse
class updateRewardsPercentageByTokens(Resource):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-a', nargs="+", type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-b', nargs="+", type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-fromA',help="please put the from address")
    parser.add_argument('-gas',type=int,help="please put the amount of gas")

    def get (self): 
        nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account)
        data = updateRewardsPercentageByTokens.parser.parse_args([])
        fromAddress = data.fromA
        gas = data.gas
        a = data.a
        b = data.b
        c = dict(echelonMaxValue="100000",percentage="2")
        #{'newEchlonArray': ['1', '10000']}
        #{'echelonMaxValue': ['10000'], 'percentage': [1]}
        #{"echelonMaxValue": 1000, "percentage": 1}
        print(c)
        try : 
            print('here')
            print(a)
            print(b)
            print(gas)
            print(fromAddress)
            tx = contract.functions.updateRewardsPercentageByTokens({'newEchlonArray':[500000000000000000000,1]}).transact({

                'chainId': 3,
                'from': fromAddress,
                'gas' : gas,
                'gasPrice' : web3.toWei('100', 'gwei'),
                'nonce': nonce,

            })
            
            #sign the transaction
            signed_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx,wallet_private_key)
            #get the transaction hash 
            tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
            print(web3.toHex(tx_hash))

            #waiting for the trasaction receipt
            receipt = web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash,timeout=3600, poll_latency=0.1)

            #convert the result from dict to json
            tx_dict = dict(receipt)                   
            tx_json = Web3.toJSON(tx_dict) 
           
            #return result sous format json
            return json.loads(tx_json),201
        except Exception as e : 
            print (str(e))
           
            return {'error': str(e)},401
```

Answer (score 3):

You are just not giving the inputs in the right format.

I used a simplified version of your contract :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Example {

    struct EchelonReward {
        uint256 echelonMaxValue;
        uint256 percentage;
    }

    function updateRewardsPercentageByTokens(EchelonReward[] memory newEchlonArray) public {
        // FUNCTION BODY
    }
}
```

The ABI entry for the `updateRewardsPercentageByTokens` inputs is the following :

```
"internalType": "struct Example.EchelonReward[]",
                "name": "newEchlonArray",
                "type": "tuple[]"
```

Where you can see that the input `type` is an array of tuple, but in your code you are giving : `{'newEchlonArray':[500000000000000000000,1]}` which is of type `Dict` and cannot be unambiguously transformed to an array of tuple.

Simply changing this :

```
tx = contract.functions.updateRewardsPercentageByTokens({'newEchlonArray':[500000000000000000000,1]}).transact({

                'chainId': 3,
                'from': fromAddress,
                'gas' : gas,
                'gasPrice' : web3.toWei('100', 'gwei'),
                'nonce': nonce,

            })
```

To use the correct input type :

```
tx = contract.functions.updateRewardsPercentageByTokens([(500000000000000000000,1)]).transact({

                'chainId': 3,
                'from': fromAddress,
                'gas' : gas,
                'gasPrice' : web3.toWei('100', 'gwei'),
                'nonce': nonce,

            })
```

Should solve your problem.

If that's useful, here's the code I used to test your contract :

```
from web3 import Web3
import json

ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8545"
ABI_PATH = "abi.json";
CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512";

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(ENDPOINT))
accounts = web3.eth.accounts;

with open(ABI_PATH) as file:
    CONTRACT_ABI = json.load(file);

contract = web3.eth.contract(address=CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi=CONTRACT_ABI);

// Array of tuples - You can also make an Array of Arrays , the conversion
// has no ambiguity as long as the dimensions are respected.
newEchlonArray = [(0,0), (1, 1)]

contract.functions.updateRewardsPercentageByTokens(newEchlonArray).call();
```

---

On a side note, you'd be better off not setting the `nonce` and `gas` parameters yourself. Web3.py will take care of it according to your account nonce, and the gas requirements respectively.